# Fill char array with input and I dont understand the output

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I'm learning the `char` arrays in C. I wrote a little program which works with functions and reads input from terminal and on `EOF` will `printf` the `char` array.

If I enter, for example: `hello my name is` and press enter, I receive this output: `hello my z Í²`

I don't understand where the `z Í²` comes from. Can someone explain it to me?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAXLENGTH = 10;
int getLine(char[], int);

int main(void) {
    char inputString[MAXLENGTH];

    getLine(inputString, MAXLENGTH);
    printf("%s", inputString);

    return 0;
}

// Functions:
int getLine(char destArray[], int length) {
    int returnLength;
    int input;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        if ((input = getchar()) != EOF) {
            destArray[i] = input;
            returnLength = i;
        }
    }
    return returnLength;
}
```

Comment: `hello my name is` doesn't fit in a char array of size 10. And you're missing the nul-terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not store a null terminator at the end of the destination array in `getLine()`.
- you should stop read from `stdin` when you get a newline (`'\n'`) or an `EOF` value.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAXLENGTH = 10;
int getLine(char[], int);

int main(void) {
    char inputString[MAXLENGTH];

    getLine(inputString, MAXLENGTH);
    printf("%s\n", inputString);

    return 0;
}

// Functions:
int getLine(char destArray[], int length) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
            break; 
        destArray[i] = c;
    }
    destArray[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Running this program will show that `hello my name is` does not fit in the destination array as the program's output will be `hello my`

In your program, you were not storing anything beyond the end of the buffer, because you correctly test `i < length - 1`, but `printf` did read beyond the 9-th byte set by `getLine()` and printed whatever contents was in memory at those addresses until it finds a null byte, which is undefined behavior. The weird output is a benign side effect of undefined behavior, the program could have crashed too. The bytes in the memory probably correspond to values stored in the stack for the `main()` function local frame and return address. Different compilers, different platforms or even different invocations of the same program could produce different output (the latter may seem unlikely, but would happen on OS/X because of stack randomisation).

Comment: Thank you! I understand, so the error was staht i didnt store a null terminator. But can you explain me why i got such a weird output from my first version of the code? Where does the ``z Í²`` come from? Just to understand what happend there :)

Comment: Calling `printf` with an unterminated string invokes *Undefined Behavior*. Anything can happen. Likely, `printf` continued to output characters from your stack beyond the end of the array until a random `0` was encountered in memory. The intervening characters were likely outside the printable range of values and so gibberish was output for each character not within the printable range of characters.

Comment: @Jimmy: I amended the answer with an explanation for the bogus output.